# New Relic Alert for any specific error only

Tags: newrelic

What’s the nature of the problem?

We have retry mechanism for any retryable and non-retryable event, so we need alert with error details on New Relic whenever we get any NonRetryable error, such that we can take action on it. This alert might come on Slack or on Email or JIRA.

I tried the following things to achieve :

1. Created NRQL alert base on metric timeslice, it gives me alert on violation trigger.   But the problem is data aggregator window. If I receive multiple Non-Retyable error with in minutes, It give me single alert and does not create other alert until unless I don’t close previous opened violation.
2. Used Errors & Inbox alert. It solves the problem of multple alert but I don’t have option to choose send alert only for Non-Retryable error specifically., It gives alert for any kind of new Error group.

Can we have any other way to achieve following things :

1. Alert for specific error
2. Alert to specific team or person Multiple
3. Alerts for parallel calls.